# LibGDX Problems passing textures to shader

Tags: java, libgdx, glsl, shader

I am trying to pass a texture to my shader, but when the sampler2D uniform I am setting to my texture has same content as the u_sampler2D holding the current texture provided by OpenGL.

Here is how I set the uniform (this is in my SpriteBatch's begin method before calling super.begin()):

```
texture.bind();
this.getShader().begin();
this.getShader().setUniformi("u_LightMap",0);
this.getShader().setUniformf("u_camOffset", new Vector3(inputMethod.getCameraOffsetX(), inputMethod.getCameraOffsetY(), inputMethod.getZoom()));
this.getShader().end();
```

This is my testing shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

uniform vec4 gl_FragCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;
uniform sampler2D u_LightMap;
uniform vec3 u_cam;
uniform vec2 resolution;
void main () {
    vec4 lightColor = texture2D(u_LightMap, gl_FragCoord);
    gl_FragColor = lightColor;
}
```

Where is the problem? ~BeefEX

Comment: you never set the shader in the SpriteBatch. But if you'd do that then you'd have a collision on texture unit, so better use e.g. texture unit 1. But that's just guessing, without seeing the actual code, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Yes I am setting the shader, in start method of main class. And for the texture number, I tried many numbers, incliding constants from OpenGL wrapper.

Comment: You didnt say what went wrong. Black texture? Are you sure the shader compiled? If ShaderProgram.pedantic is true, the shader as it is now might fail to compile due to unused uniforms.

Comment: I said what went wrong, the texture in u_LightMap is same as the one in u_sampler2D.

Comment: And I am sure I am setting it to different one.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code you're calling in super.begin(). It's binding the texture of the sprites to the same unit you just bound your other texture to, overwriting it. Bind your custom texture to unit one, and then change the GL active texture unit back to 0 before calling super.

Comment: Well, this code is from LibGDX wiki, but I will try it.